# Show that this extension of function fields over $\mathbb{F}_{81}$ is normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

> Let $\mathbb{F}_{81}$ be the finite field with $81$ elements, $L=Quot(\mathbb{F}_{81}[T])$ and $K=\mathbb{F}_{81}(T^{10})\subseteq L$. Show, that the extension $L/K$ is normal. Hint: How does the factorization of $X^n-a$ look like?

My (old) attempt:

> I know that $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}^{\times}$ is cyclic. If we look at
> $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ and a factor $k$ of $n$, I can find subgroups $U$
> with order $p^k-1$ so that  \begin{align*} X^{p^k}-X=X\cdot\prod_{u\in U} (X-u) \end{align*} In my case, I have
> $\mathbb{F}_{3^4}$ and $k=1,2,4$
>
> Could that be of any relevance here? I also think that the
> Frobenius-Automorphism might be useful. My main problem is that I
> cannot imagine $L$ and $K$.
>
> I think $x\in K$ can be written as
> $x=\frac{a_nT^{10n}+...+a_1T^{10}+a_0}{b_mT^{10m}+...+b_1T^{10}+b_0}$
> and $y\in L$ can be written as
> $y=\frac{a_rT^{r}+...+a_1T+a_0}{b_sT^{s}+...+b_1T+b_0}$
>
> I'd like to have some ideas/tips/... that push me in the right
> direction.

My new attempt:

As discussed in the comments, it seems that it suffices that if for any polynomial $Q\in K[X]$ where $K$ doesn't split $Q$, the field extension $L$ is a splitting field of $Q$, then $L/K$ is normal.

I can look at $P(X) = X^{10}-T^{10}\in K[X]$ and this polynomial has obviously a root in $L$ (because $T\in L$). My other roots would be $\zeta_{10}^1 T,...,\zeta_{10}^{9} T$, where $\zeta_{10}$ is the primitive $10-$root of unity.

But all these roots are equal to $T$ when raised to the power of $10$, so $P(X)=X^{10}-T^{10}=(X-T)^{10}$ in $L$ and there is no smaller field extension that splits $P$ because $L=Quot(\mathbb{F}_{81}[T])$ is already the smallest field containing $T$.

Then $L/K$ is normal.

Any flaws in that proof?

Comment: That hint is saying that, if $K$ has a primitive $n$-th root of unity $\zeta_n$, then $X^n-a=\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}(X-\zeta_n^j\sqrt[n]a)$.

Comment: Well, to show that an extension of a field $k$ is normal, you can exhibit it as splitting field of a $k$-polynomial. Does this hint help?

Comment: @Lubin So you're saying I can look at any Polynomial $P\in K[X]$ (That I cannot split in linear factors in $K$) and if I then prove that $L$ is a splitting field of $P$, $L/K$ is normal?

Comment: @Yai0Phah Okay, so from what I understand I can look at $P(X) = X^n-T^n$ and this polynomial has obviously a root in $L$ (because $T\in L$). My other roots would be $\zeta_n^1 T,...,\zeta_n^{n-1} T$. So $P(X)=X^n-T^n=(X-T)^n$ in $L$ and there is no smaller field extension that splits $P$ because $L=Quot(\mathbb{F}_{81}[T])$ is already the smallest field containing $T$. Is that somewhat right? I'll edit it above as my new attempt.

Comment: There are no conditions on the $K$-polynomial (or set of $K$-polynomials, even infinite) whatever. Just adjoin *all* roots of the polynomial or set of polynomials, and you get a normal extension. (Notice I didn’t say anything about linear factors — that comes without charge.)

Comment: @Lubin Okay, I think I get that. Is my new attempt (postet in my question above) better? A collegue said that it's not correct and that I need to look at $X^{30}-T^{30}$ because for $T$ to be the only root it must be divisible by $3$ (because the characteristic of $\mathbb{F}_{81}$ is $3$). Is that true?

Comment: You proof as of now (2111141100) looks fine to me. The minimal polynomial for $T$ over $K(T^{10}=\tau)$ (thus defining $\tau$ as $T^{10}$) is clearly $X^{10}-\tau$. You get the splitting field by adjoining all roots of this polynomial, namely $T$ and its product with tenth roots of unity, which providentiallly are in your base field $K=\Bbb F_{81}$.